# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfile.py'

Tags: import, module

So I have trawled through other very similar issues and tried many variations but I cannot get this to work.

I have created code in a separate file under the following structure:

/somefolder/  #this is where my main code resides
/somefolder/src/ this is where my myfile.py  resides that I want to import.

My main code starts as follows:

```
import os.path
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../src'))

import myfile as mine
```

but then I get teh following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfile'
```

Any assistance would be very welcome.

Comment: What is your current directory while starting the main program?

Comment: `C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1` The module is in `C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\src`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current directory is `PythonApplication1`, you can follow these steps to access `myfile` module.

1. create `__init__.py` file in both `PythonApplication1` and
   `PythonApplication1\src` directories
2. Now import myfile as `from src import myfile as mine`